# Symfony route to file misunderstanding

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I had an intention to dynamically generate a `robots.txt` file for different domain names.

I removed the file from `/web/` directory. 
I added

```
bits_cb.common:
    resource: "@BitsClientoboxBundle/Controller/CommonController.php"
    type: annotation
```

to routing.yml.

I added

```
/**
 * @Route("/robots.txt", name="robots")
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
 //
}
```

to CommonController.php.

The `debug:router` console command there is route:

```
robots    ANY    ANY    ANY    /robots.txt
```

But if I try to get from **http://{{sitename}}/robots.txt** it returns 404.
To be sure, if I change

```
* @Route("/robots.txt", name="robots")
```

to

```
* @Route("/robots", name="robots")
```

and get from **http://{{sitename}}/robots** it works okay.

Comment: Could it be that you have a rewrite rule in your apache configuration that causes your webserver to not access your application properly? Could you post your .htaccess file in your web/ folder and/or your vhost configuration?

Comment: can you escape the dot `\.` I don't think its parsed properly and tries to look for the file

Comment: This should work as is, make sure to clear cache for prod env or check `domain/app_dev.php/robots.txt` for dev env.